# Rev.v le_antisymmetric

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I came to this point:

```
Theorem le_antisymmetric :
  antisymmetric le.
Proof.
  unfold antisymmetric. intros a b H1 H2. generalize dependent a.
  induction b as [|b' IH].
  - intros. inversion H1. reflexivity.
  - intros.
```

Output:

```
b' : nat
IH : forall a : nat, a <= b' -> b' <= a -> a = b'
a : nat
H1 : a <= S b'
H2 : S b' <= a
------------------------------------------------------
a = S b'
```

My plan was to use transitivity of `le`:

a <= b -> b <= c -> a <= c

And substitute a := a, b := (S b') and c := a.

So we'll get:

a <= (S b') -> (S b') <= a -> a <= a

I'll use H1 and H2 as 2 hypotheses needed and get Ha: a <= a. Then do an inversion upon it, and get the only
way construct this is a = a.

But what syntax should I use to apply transitivity with 2 my hypotheses to get Ha?

Comment: `Goal forall x y, x <= y -> y <= x -> x = y. induction x; destruct y; subst; [reflexivity | inversion 2 | inversion 1 | intros; apply f_equal, IHx; apply le_S_n; trivial]. Qed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first induction over `b` here seems unnecessary. Consider `le`:

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
    le_n : n <= n | le_S : forall m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m
```

You should instead be inspecting `H1` first. If it's `le_n`, then that's equality, and you're done. If it's `le_S`, then presumably that's somehow impossible.

```
intros a b [ | b' H1] H2.
- reflexivity.
```

This leaves us with

```
a, b, b' : nat (* b is extraneous *)
H1 : a <= b'
H2 : S b' <= a
______________________________________(1/1)
a = S b'
```

*Now*, transitivity makes sense. It can give you `S b' <= b'`, which is impossible. You can derive a contradiction using induction (I think), or you can use an existing lemma. The whole proof is thus.

```
intros a b [ | b' H1] H2.
- reflexivity.
- absurd (S b' <= b').
  + apply Nat.nle_succ_diag_l.
  + etransitivity; eassumption.
```

That last bit is one way to use transitivity. `etransitivity` turns the goal `R x z` into `R x ?y` and `R ?y z`, for a new existential variable `?y`. `eassumption` then finds assumptions that match that pattern. Here, specifically, you get goals `S b' <= ?y` and `?y <= b`, filled by `H2` and `H1` respectively. You can also give the intermediate value explicitly, which lets you drop the `e`xistential prefix.

```
transitivity a; assumption.
```

Comment: I used `apply le_Sn_n.` instead of `apply Nat.nle_succ_diag_l.`